# JavaFX. Why fixed radius size gradient can't be positioned?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I want to make a `radial-gradient` background and place it in bottom right corner of my `Region` element. I want it to have a fixed radius of 30px. According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint) I can either specify percentage or fixed size. Problem is when type in fixed size my gradient is being rendered in top left corner, but when I use percentage it acts like supposed to. What am I missing?

Code and result for fixed size:

```
radial-gradient(focus-angle 0deg, focus-distance 0%, center 100% 100%, radius 30px, #ffb06a 0%, #cc3671 50%, #3f003a 100%);
```

[image]

Code and result for percentage:

```
radial-gradient(focus-angle 0deg, focus-distance 0%, center 100% 100%, radius 30%, #ffb06a 0%, #cc3671 50%, #3f003a 100%);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeradial-gradient)

> Percentage and length sizes can not be mixed in a single gradient function.

This means if you want to have a fixed radius of 30px, then the center point should also be defined using *px*, for example:

```
radial-gradient(focus-angle 0deg, focus-distance 0%, center 600px 400px, radius 30px, #ffb06a 0%, #cc3671 50%, #3f003a 100%);
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and genius! But what if I want responsive positioning? Like I want my gradient to be always at 80% 60% point, but if I use percentage on radius it stretches shape. Because window is not square but rather rectangle, shape of my gradient is also ellipse rather circle. Is it possible to specify radius in percentage but maintain circle shape of gradient?

Comment: The docs says "Percentage values are relative to the size of the area being filled". It means the percentage value you use is relative to the area you fill in. So the gradient will be an ellipsis if the area is not a square. Seems that you will have to do some trade-off here. Alternative solution would be using an additional Rectangle Shape on top of the main window so that the gradient is circular, for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1WlL.png